# Hover effect with a text box inside an a href image

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't figure it out how I can fix this problem with hover effect on image with a href.
so I made 2 types of different codes. in the first image the hover effect perfect match the size of the box:

[image]

The second image not. (In the code the image 1 it's set as image background, the second one as image)

[image]

Also, if i resize the screen (mobile phone screen), the size of the first image became so little.

[image]

Can anybody help me with this code? I need only one example so I can do the same for the other a href images.

This is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 0 0.65rem;
}

.gallery-item {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 300px);
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  }
  .gallery-item:first-child {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(2),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(3),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(4) {}
  .gallery-item:nth-child(5),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/5;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(11),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(13) {
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  }
  .gallery-item:first-child {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(2),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(3),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(4) {}
  .gallery-item:nth-child(5),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/5;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(11),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(13) {
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
}

.product-1 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/VK_SS21-14280robeshama_600x.jpg?v=1607788637");
}

.middle {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-item a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery-item a i {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  border-radius: .4rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.gallery-item a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.gallery-item a:hover i,
.gallery-item a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> Image Gallery </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtRS4K2L/brigitte-bardot-1-800x400.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/q7j09Dt0/schermata-2020-09-09-alle-18-35-19-1599669344.png"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j5DN1qbT/4e3f95459e0ea75731c812c6bb5b2b98.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/2ySS4ZNn/okok.jpg" style="object-fit: contain"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/dresses/products/shama-white-dress" class="product-1">
        <i class="middle">
            <div class="text">Discover More</div>
          </i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/dresses/products/short-boho-rich-dress">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/Schermata2021-04-19alle12.14.07_600x.png?v=1618827354">
        <i class="middle">
              <div class="text">Discover More</div>
            </i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kgSp097x/7af20cc13f08d23f6b56bbafcba9c894.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/hG6bcQMv/Brigitte-Bardot-beach-robe-red-straw-hat-1960s.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/JhZtHyMG/409debab4e6404f1ba9ccd2a0caf57d5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xWrMtRX/port-saint-tropez-g08oplu.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/sunglasses/products/edith">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/PELLE_1-Modifica_600x.jpg?v=1618827011">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7LZvzWXt/A.jpg" style="object-fit: contain"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/shoes/products/bubbles-flats">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/dhdhdhdh_400x.jpg?v=1618408909">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bN5rw74C/6ac52adef5323f8859c853b6aeae2ebe.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because the img tag shifts the block to display. Here is a screen - https://ibb.co/Y37BNTx. And why are you turning divs into the <i> tag?

Comment: Use absolute positioning for the display block (.gallery-item a i), and don't wrap the div in a <i> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've added: `position: absolute;` and removed `left: 50%;`
Properties like `top`, `left` etc has no effect when they are in  static position (normal flow)

```
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 0 0.65rem;
}

.gallery-item {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 300px);
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  }
  .gallery-item:first-child {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(2),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(3),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(4) {}
  .gallery-item:nth-child(5),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/5;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(11),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(13) {
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  }
  .gallery-item:first-child {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(2),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(3),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(4) {}
  .gallery-item:nth-child(5),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/5;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
  .gallery-item:nth-child(11),
  .gallery-item:nth-child(13) {
    border: 6px solid #333;
  }
}

.product-1 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/VK_SS21-14280robeshama_600x.jpg?v=1607788637");
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-item a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery-item a .middle {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  border-radius: .4rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.gallery-item a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.gallery-item a:hover .middle,
.gallery-item a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> Image Gallery </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtRS4K2L/brigitte-bardot-1-800x400.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/q7j09Dt0/schermata-2020-09-09-alle-18-35-19-1599669344.png"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j5DN1qbT/4e3f95459e0ea75731c812c6bb5b2b98.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/2ySS4ZNn/okok.jpg" style="object-fit: contain"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/dresses/products/shama-white-dress" class="product-1">
        <div class="middle">
          <i class="text">Discover More</i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/dresses/products/short-boho-rich-dress">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/Schermata2021-04-19alle12.14.07_600x.png?v=1618827354">
        <div class="middle">
          <i class="text">Discover More</i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kgSp097x/7af20cc13f08d23f6b56bbafcba9c894.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/hG6bcQMv/Brigitte-Bardot-beach-robe-red-straw-hat-1960s.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/JhZtHyMG/409debab4e6404f1ba9ccd2a0caf57d5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xWrMtRX/port-saint-tropez-g08oplu.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/sunglasses/products/edith">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/PELLE_1-Modifica_600x.jpg?v=1618827011">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7LZvzWXt/A.jpg" style="object-fit: contain"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://ali-da.com/collections/shoes/products/bubbles-flats">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0425/9040/4758/products/dhdhdhdh_400x.jpg?v=1618408909">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bN5rw74C/6ac52adef5323f8859c853b6aeae2ebe.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So it worked, but need to do a few changes. 
I tried it, and the first image now (when it goes to mobile screen size, it disappears. I think it can be fixed by changing it from background img to simple img like the second one.
The only fact is that when i start to decrease the screen size, the button inside the hover is not centered.

Comment: It seems centred in the above demo at very low resolution, like 500px... Do you mean the text inside button?

Comment: Nono, i mean the box. I fixed the first problem of img, by changin it in the html.
Also i changed the fact that the text seems not centered by deleting "font-size: 3rem;" in the .gallery-item a .middle.
At 773px*937px screen, seems like the box is not centered in the img. The center line is starting from the top of the box and not from the center of the box

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with a snippet of what you have right now, ad you can properly format the description in it

Comment: Ok, btw thx for your advices. It really helps me out. Thx a lot!